# How to printout a help to terminal window from compiled .exe file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I'd like to show short description about program for users.

I have .py file compiled to .exe by pyinstaller and try to use the following code to show help if any arguments were passed to the .exe file from terminal window.

```
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    # argv[1] has your filename
    sys.stdout.write("Description about program...")
    sys.exit("Terminating")
```

If any arguments passed to .exe the program finishes by sys.exit command, but no printout shown in terminal window.

Comment: why aren't you using `print`?

Comment: @בנימיןכהן, it also does not work

Comment: what happens when you don't execute the `sys.exit("Terminating")` statement?

Comment: @בנימיןכהן, the program goes on, but I don't like to do it when printing out the help

Comment: But does it print the line?

Comment: @בנימיןכהן, there is no printout at all

Comment: try `print(sys.stdout)`. maybe your `stdout` is not what you think it is

Comment: @בנימיןכהן, tried without success (so it works fine in IDLE by printing out to Shell, but not worked in terminal window after compiling to .exe)

Comment: does it print the line `Terminating`?

Comment: @בנימיןכהן, no. It prints (in IDLE):
<idlelib.run.PseudoOutputFile object at 0x03233270>

Comment: i meant if the `sys.exit` call print that line...

Comment: @בנימיןכהן. there is no printout at all, not from sys.exit nor from print(sys.stdout)

Comment: can you send the source and the file so I can check if it happens to me too?

Comment: Use `pyinstaller -F script.py` to generate your executable. This should print the output.

Comment: I suggest reading up on the argparser module
https://docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used -w flag with pyinstaller when generated .exe. 
That was the clue, it suppresses console output even if you launch the program through terminal window.
Thank you everybody.

```
-w, --windowed, --noconsole
    Windows and Mac OS X: do not provide a console window for standard i/o. On Mac OS X this also triggers building an OS X .app bundle. This option is ignored in *NIX systems.
```